# In a random graph, show that there are constants $c,d$ such that $\mathbb{P}[c(G_{n,\frac{1}{2}}\geq \frac{n^2}{8}+cn^{\frac{3}{2}}]\leq e^{-dn}$

Tags: graph-theory

A balanced cut $C = (X, Y )$ in a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a partition of the vertex
set into two parts $X$ and $Y$ such that $X ∪ Y = V$ and $|X| = |Y | = n/2$ (here we assume
that n is even). The size of $C$ is the number of edges of $G$ which have one endpoint in $X$
and the other one in $Y$. Let $c(G)$ the maximum size of any balanced cut of $G$. Let $G_n,1/2$
be the random graph generated by including each edge with probability 1/2 independently.
Show that there are constants $c,d>0$ such that, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[c(G_{n,\frac{1}{2}}\geq \frac{n^2}{8}+cn^{\frac{3}{2}}]\leq e^{-dn}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a graph, $X,Y$ be a cut, and let $c_{X,Y}$ denote its size. Then $c_{X,Y}(G) \leq c(G)$, hence 
$$ \mathbb P( c_{X,Y}(G) >x) \leq \mathbb P(c(G)>x)\quad \mbox{and} \quad \mathbb P(c_{X,Y}(G)<x) \ge \mathbb P (c(G)<x) $$

For fixed cut $ c_{X,Y}(G) \sim Binom(n^2/4,1/2)$, i.e.
$$ \mathbb P (c_{X,Y}(G) > x) = \sum_{k>x} \binom{n^2/4}{k} \frac{1}{2^{n^2/4}}  $$
Furthermore
$$ \mathbb P (c(G)>x) \le \sum_{X,Y\mbox{ bal. cut}} \mathbb P(c_{X,Y}>x)\le \binom{n}{n/2} \mathbb P (c_{X,Y}(G) > x) \tag{1}\label{appr} $$ 
One can apply CLT for $c_{X,Y}$, i.e.
\begin{align}\label{CLT} \mathbb P \bigg(c_{X,Y}(G)- \frac{n^2}{8} > \sqrt{n^2/16}\cdot x\bigg) \approx 1 -\Phi(x)\tag{2} \end{align}

According to Lin (1989): $1-\Phi(x) \approx 0.5\exp(-0.717x -0.416x^2) $ for $x>0$.

Now we apply Stirling's approximation 
$$ \binom{n}{n/2} \approx \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi n}\cdot 2^n $$
By choosing $x=2\sqrt n$ and $d=0.414$ and $c=1/2$ we proved the theorem.
Using this and combining \eqref{appr} and \eqref{CLT} with Lin's result we arrive at
$$ \mathbb P(c(G)>n^2/8 + x\cdot n/4)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-0.717x - 0.414x^2 + n\log 2-\frac12 \log n) .  $$
Now choose $x=2\sqrt n$, then
$$ \mathbb P(c(G)>n^2/8 +  n^{3/2}/2)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-1.434\sqrt n - 0.828 n + n\log 2-\frac{1}2 \log n)\leq \exp(-0.135n) ,  $$
since $\log 2= 0.6931+ \Omega(10^{-5})$. Choosing $c=1/2$ and $d=-0.135$ we proved the theorem.

**Note**: I assumed that $n$ is large enough in order for the error term in \eqref{CLT} to be small. For more info on the error term refer to the Berry-Esséen theorem.